# Black Lines on edge of character

Tags: rendering

I'm making a render of my Minecraft character, but there are black lines appearing on the edges of the arms and legs. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9fk7mmup0zai326/AiltonicChristmas.blend

Comment: When asking questions please *do not* rely only on file and several words description that there is something wrong; include screenshots of the problem and improve your description according to them. Lastly for files please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but the reason you're seeing that is because you have two nearly-overlapping meshes for that character's arms and legs, and you're seeing one poking through the other.

For the right arm for example, you have both char.Mesh.Arm_R.002 and char.Mesh.Layer.Arm_R.

It seems possible that one of these meshes is meant to be the arm itself while another is meant to be clothing, but they aren't placed correctly for this effect.

[image]